# nodejs notification system

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm doing a **notification system** for my website.
A notification systeme like `facebook`. Or `stackoverflow`.
I have **2** problems.

1. How store in db ? I can store ALL notifications in the user document ? or in a document apart (because i think monogdb is limited for size in a document ?) Or, store intelligently ? (using inc, or a value (see: true/false) in db, with query sophisticated)
2. How do for brought at the page ? For exemple, when i click in a link in my `inbox` for `stackoverflow`, i'm redirect to the page. But me, i have a system that is `multipage` for **exemple**: I have 100 friends. There are listed 30 per page. So when i click on the notification i can't redirect to the because it's impossible to know the good page (users can be removed).

Thank you very much !
And if you have another ideas, tell me. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

(sorry for my english, i'm french)

For the first problem, i realize that i have to wait the time comes to choose my structure. Because my notification is .. a little complicated, so advance to the feeling.

For the second, i solved the problem. I explain:
(I take the exemple of friends because it's easy to undestand.)
I stored my data like this:

```
{
  friends: [
    {_id: xxxxx, ts: xxxx},
    {_id: xxxxx, ts: xxxx}
  ]
}
```

Imagine i display all friends: 30 per page.
The problems are:

- when i want to display all friends i cant sort using mongo. (a little problem)
- If i want to lead a user to this list (30 per page) at a special friend, always keeping the `sort` by `ts`. I can't know the page. The uniq solution is to take all document.
  But: veryyy bad in performance.

So, i store like this:

```
{
  friends: {
    xxxx: {ts:xxx},
    xxxx: {ts:xxx}
  }
}
```

Know i can sort the document, with use skip and limit.
So if i want a portion, i do not need to take all documents.

To know the page, i just do the number of < or > to the ts, i have for exemple 11 friends who are > to the ts of the friends that i want, and do a count for all friends (ex: 50 friends) with 50 and 11, i can guess the page.

Is this solution is good ?
- i need a count
- a query to know the number of > or <
and i can take the page where is listed the friend, keeping `the sort ts`

You can don't understand why i use a count. I need because they are not store in the same docment.

**2 EDIT:**

The problem with this solution, is that i need to make `query object` and `update object` outside of the `mongo query` (ex: for do `friends.xxxxxx: {$exists:true}`

ps: And what advantages are to use `ts` instead of `date` for mongodb ?
I'm using `ts` but i think i will store `date`, and no `ts`.

**3 EDIT**

I will do like `Sammaye`. Store in separate document. Take a look at: http://mongly.com/Multiple-Collections-Versus-Embedded-Documents/#1 and http://openmymind.net/2012/1/30/MongoDB-Embedded-Documents-vs-Multiple-Collections/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Stennie make a pretty complete answer.

However recently I did a similar thing in PHP for my website. The first thing to understand is whether you are doing a notification system or a wall (the two are very different), it seems unclear to me and I am not sure what you mean by:

> How do for brought at the page ? For exemple, when i click in a link
>   in my inbox for stackoverflow, i'm redirect to the page. But me, i
>   have a system that is multipage for exemple: I have 100 friends. There
>   are listed 30 per page. So when i click on the notification i can't
>   redirect to the because it's impossible to know the good page (users
>   can be removed).

That is not very good English and is very confusing when I read it. If you can expand on that I am sure people can answer better.

For a notification system I found that a large collection of notification objects also worked. So I had a schema like:

```
{
    _id: {},
    to_user: ObjectId{},
    user_id: ObjectId{}, // Originating user
    custom_text: "has posted a new comment on your wall post",
    read: false,
    ts: MongoDate()
}
```

And this would literally be the document I have to produce notifications. Each time a user commits an action that generates a notification it writes a new row to the DB with `to_user` being populated each time with each user needing to be notified. As for multiple users commiting the same action I actually convert the `user_id` field in a list of `OjbectId`'s so I can say:

`Sam, Dan and Mike all commented on your wall post`

I then query by `ts` storing the last `ts` that the user looked at in their row allowing me to do a range based query on the newest notifications each time. This works quite well for sharding and querying in my personal experience.

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 1):

Whether to [embed or link](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design#SchemaDesign-EmbeddingandLinking) is a common question for data modelling in MongoDB.  If your number of notifications is going to be unbounded, you are likely going to be better saving these in a separate collection.

The current 16Mb document limit actually isn't as much as an issue as some other considerations:

- A performance issue you may encounter by including all notifications in a single document is that fast-growing documents may also need to be relocated in the database more frequently (see [Padding Factor](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Padding+Factor#PaddingFactor-Overview)).
- You may want to be applying multiple updates to a document (such as setting a "read" flag on notifications) in a very short period of time, which means more contention for updating the same document (see [Atomic Operations](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations)).

In order to implement paging you can use [limit()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Blimit%28%29%7D%7D) in combination with a range query or [skip()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Bskip%28%29%7D%7D).  A range query (eg. based on an indexed `notificationDate`) will make more effective use of indexes and perform better than `skip()` as your collection grows.